# Custom server and OpenVPN server on same machine

Tags: nginx, openvpn, tunnel

Here's the environment:
An OpenVpn server and an nginx server live on the same machine (with only one network interface eth0, plus the tun0 interface created by openvpn).
On the nginx server i've a service that get the public ip of a NAT-ted client and test the connection to this ip using a opened port (opened via port-forwarding ).

Now the problem:
If this particular clients it's already connected to the openvpn server and the nginx server use the client public IP, the packet will never reach the client.
If i disconnect the client from the VPN, the packet will reach the client using the public IP.

It's seems that all the packet that are sended to a public IP that it's already connected via openvpn are sended automatically via tunnel.

Why? Can i avoid this?

My goal is to verify the connectivity and, if the client is correctly reached via public IP, disconnect the client from the VPN.

Thanks